# Saving 'Data' Discord bot Python?

Tags: python, bots, discord

Today, I got a idea, of make a "anti-links" code for my bot, for people who don't want others to post links, like youtube, invite links...

That wouldn't be hard, I'd for sure add a few if message.content.startswith(), and check it.

However, not all server owners may want it. How could I possibly make it be enabled/disabled and saving, like storage that in the server x it shall or not be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Create a config file and make the bot read it on every boot.

```
antilink_enable = 1
```

It's useful as you can store multiple lines of config and won't need to enable/disable its function on every run.

Creating a database is a good option in case you want to expand what your bot can do in the future but a simple .txt can solve your problem.